# jQuery slider for an image and description

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slider for my portfolio website.

To help express what I am trying to achieve, here is an image of what i want it to look like...
[image]

basically when you hit the next or previous arrow, both the screen shot and the descriptive text slide indivually  (like a carousel effect) displaying the next screenshot and description. I am guessing this is done in jQuery, but the other jQuery sliders i have looked at and tried out slide the whole lot over at once.

does anyone know how to achieve what I am trying to do, or knows of a website that has a tutorial?

many thanks in advance

Tom

Comment: Just to clarify, when an arrow is clicked, you want, for example, the laptop image to slide off to the left, and the description to slide off to the right, then have the next portfolio item's image and description slide in?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the tag jquery-ui-slider refers to a slider that changes value based on where the hand on the slider is , completely different part of jquery,

but anyways , you need a slider plugin that allows you to slide content divs , [here](http://www.aakashweb.com/jquery-plugins/lite-content-slider/#docs) is an example of one

then in the div you would place the image and the description and style it to look pretty with css

like this maybe

```
<div class="sliderWrap">
     <div class="sliderContent">
          <img src="..." />
          Content 1 goes here
     </div>

     <div class="sliderContent">
          <img src="..." />
          Content 2 goes here
     </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: thank you scott, I removed the incorrect tag. I will give this a go and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very high level question so I can only give you a similar answer. Here's how I would tackle your design. Steps:

1) Layout your slides and descriptions in an UL. Each IL containing the identical layouts but with different images and descriptions.

2) Using CSS, style your UL to show all LI elements as inline blocks for fixed widths.

3) Place your UL in a wrapper DIV with overflow set to hidden

4) Using JQuery or simple javascript simply increase or decrease the relative position of the UL in increments equal to the fixed width of your LI. JQuery will help you animate the motion more easily (see JQuery Animate()).

Your basic structure would look like:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="slide1.png">Slide 1 description text Slide 1 description text Slide 1 description text Slide 1 description text </li>
        <li><img src="slide2.png">Slide 2 description text Slide 2 description text Slide 2 description text Slide 2 description text </li>
        <li><img src="slide3.png">Slide 3 description text Slide 3 description text Slide 3 description text Slide 3 description text </li>
        <li><img src="slide4.png">Slide 4 description text Slide 4 description text Slide 4 description text Slide 4 description text </li>
        <li><img src="slide5.png">Slide 5 description text Slide 5 description text Slide 5 description text Slide 5 description text </li>
        <li><img src="slide6.png">Slide 6 description text Slide 6 description text Slide 6 description text Slide 6 description text </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<input type="button" id="slide_left" value="LEFT"> 
<input type="button" id="slide_right" value="RIGHT">
```

This is a really basic skeleton but should be a good start. Your CSS can do the rest.

Here's the CSS:

```
#slider { width:600px; height:250px; background:url('slider_laptop_bg.png'); background-color:#eee; overflow:hidden; }
#slider ul { position:relative; left:0px; list-style-type:none; width:5000px; hieight:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
#slider ul li { float:left; width:600px; height:250px; display:inline; padding:0px; margin:0; }
#slider ul li img { float:left; width:250px; height:200px; }
```

And here's the JQuery to enable it. Look into Animate() for fancier stuff. You need to add end of slide checks too and some other details.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#slide_left').on('click', function () {
        $('#slider ul').css('left', $('#slider ul').position().left - 608);
    });

    $('#slide_right').on('click', function () {
        $('#slider ul').css('left', $('#slider ul').position().left + 608);
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I needed something like this for a personal weekend project and figured I'd just build it out. I added my rough code above. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

@tom Whenever I need to use carousel, I use [this](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html). hope this will help you. The best part of it is that, it is responsive.